# How to annotate a third-party class constructor function with jsdoc and typescript notation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, loopbackjs, jsdoc

I'm using a framework (loopback 3) that provides classes created at runtime, I'm trying to [annotate them with JSDoc and use Typescript to enforce the types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/how-to-upgrade-to-typescript-without-anybody-noticing-part-1/). This approach works fine but I can't find a way to document the constructor though.

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} MyModel
 * @property {String} code
 * @property {String} name
 */

//[...]

/** @type {MyModel} */
const Model = app.models.Model;

const instance = new Model();
```

The Typescript compiler throws an error:

```
TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

I tried adding the `@constructor` annotation like this

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} MyModel
 * @constructor {data: object}
 * @property {String} code
 * @property {String} name
 */
```

but this renders the typedef invalid and anything annotated with it is treated as `any`.
So how do I document the constructor outside of the class?